# How to rowwise select random elements in a tibble via dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

I'm having some DNA data (alleles) for say 3 people, each row representing a SNP. In order to get some shareable test data, I would like to rowwise randomly sample data into a new tibble to get some fake DNA data which doesn't represent a real person.

For example, my initial tibble, `data`, could looks like this:

```
person_1,   person_2,   person_3

AA,         AG,         GG (i.e. data from person_1   person_2   person_3)

AC,         CC,         AC (i.e. data from person_1   person_2   person_3)

..         ..         ..
```

I would like the result to be like this:

```
random_1,  random_2,  random_3

GG,         AA,        AG (i.e. randomly assigned to person_3, person_1, person_2)

CC,         AC,        AC (i.e. randomly assigned to person_2, person_3, person_1)

...
```

I'm already able to do this with the following code:

```
data %>% 
  split(f = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
  purrr::map_dfr(~ .x[,sample(1:ncol(.x),ncol(.x))] %>% 
                   rename( setNames(object = names(.),
                                    nm = paste0("test_",sprintf("%02d", 1:length(.))))
                   )
  )
```

However, my challenge is that my tibble has more than 700.000 rows, which makes the code above extremely slow. I have tried to do the operation via `mutate()`, `rowwise()` and `across` from the `dplyr` package, but I have been unsuccessful.

Any suggestions for other approaches that are faster?

Comment: By elements do you mean observations/rows?

Comment: I mean observations in each row - so I wish, for each row in my tibble, to return a new row of the same length as the original row, but where the observations in the new row is randomly sampled from the old row. And then repeat this for every row in the tibble. Hope this makes sense (I have tried to clarity this via the example above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pmap` (from `purrr`) with `sample`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    pmap_dfr(~ sample(c(...))) %>%
    rename_all(~ str_c('random_', seq_along(.)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  random_1 random_2 random_3
#  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#1 AG       AA       GG      
#2 CC       AC       AC
```

---

Or another option is to reshape to 'long' format, do a group by `slice_sample` and then reshape back to 'wide'

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>% 
   group_by(rn) %>% 
   slice_sample(prop = 1) %>% 
   mutate(name = str_c('random_', row_number())) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#     rn random_1 random_2 random_3
#  <int> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#1     1 AG       GG       AA      
#2     2 CC       AC       AC
```

---

There is an option to use `rowwise`, but, it would be less efficient assuming the number of rows are `700000`

```
df1 %>% 
   rowwise %>%
   transmute(col1 = list(sample(c_across(everything())))) %>%
   unnest_wider(c(col1), names_repair =  ~ str_c('random_', seq_along(.)))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  random_1 random_2 random_3
#  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#1 AG       AA       GG      
#2 CC       AC       AC
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done using `apply`

```
out <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df1, 1, sample)))
names(out) <- paste0('random_', seq_along(out))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(person_1 = c("AA", "AC"), person_2 = c("AG", "CC"
), person_3 = c("GG", "AC")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The purrr solution is very elegant! And it does for sure run faster than my own solution, however it still runs for 5-7 minutes on my 4 core mac to do the computation with 700.000 rows and across 16 columns. Maybe that's a fair run time. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @aleksandereiken You could make it faster if you can split the data into multiple chunks based on some `n` number of rows and use `foreach` on each of those chunks in parallel